# Creating new Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

4 months left to my high school exam, among other things I will write IT exam, there will be theory + 3 programming exercises.

I have been coding a lot of such similar exercises, to test myself, I will be using JAVA to code during exam, and I figured out, that even while I know exactly how to solve exercise - it takes to long. So I have been thinking about trick to reduce time spent on basic things, for example creating new Class, lets say Person.java (short example)

```
private class Person
{
    private int _id;
    private String _name;
    private String _surname;
    private String _phone;
    private String _adress;

    public Person(int id, String name, String surname, String phone, String adress) 
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
        _surname = surname;
        _phone = phone;
        _adress = adress;
    }

    // and here getters for those variables ... 
}
```

Its takes couple of minutes to write all those classes holding informations, and in most cases I will be forced to write many such classes, with much more variables to solve exercises, and since I can spend only 50 minutes at every exercise (3 exercises, whole test takes 150 minutes) I'm a bit worried, so I think I will create some kind of eclipse plugin, to generate some code.

Lets say I have pressed CTRL+F12 and now little window appear, where I can fill variables, which my class should store, and of course providing their type (so in my previous class example it would be int id, String name and so on) Its noting hard obviously, but I wanted to ask, maybe there is something similar already, so I won't waste time to learn how to make my own plugin's.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I think you should spend a little time doing research into what eclipse can do for you.

Comment: I know that eclipse may reduce time a bit while coding, for example by automatically creating getters/setters, but still I'm wasting to much time to write rest, that's why I asked, anyway I will check again, maybe I will find different way. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Eclipse can do more than create getters and setters. Look at the other options in the `Source` context menu.

Comment: Thats right, I can do it with easy way, thanks for answer - it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create this type of application you have to create plugin application in eclipse.i provide you link that will help you to create eclipse plugin

http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/index.html

this tutorial contains very basic to create plugin in eclipse